# Hide/Show Radio Button List Item using javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, drop-down-menu, radiobuttonlist

I have a drop down list, say ddlTest, which has Opt1, Opt2 as items. On the same page I have a radio button list, with list items as rblItem1, rblItem2 and rblItem3. Now if a user selects Opt2 in the dropdown list, then I should hide rblItem3 or for any other option selected, I should show rblItem3 in the radio button list.

Can you please let me know if it is possible and how to do that using javascript.

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>

                <asp:RadioButtonList ID="radiobuttonlist1" runat="Server" RepeatLayout="flow" RepeatDirection="horizontal">
                         <asp:ListItem Text="Radio 1" Value="1" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>    
                           <asp:ListItem Text="Radio 2" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>

                             <asp:ListItem Text="Radio 3" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>

                                    </asp:RadioButtonList>

                                </td>

                                <td>

                                    <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="GetRadioButtonValue('<%= radiobuttonlist1.ClientID %>')" />

                                </td>

                            </tr>

                        </table>
```

Javascript Code:-

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

        // Get radio button list value

        function GetRadioButtonValue(id)

        {

            var radio = document.getElementsByName(id);

            for (var j = 0; j < radio.length; j++)

            {

                if (radio[j].checked)

                   //make hide the Item

            }

        }

</script>
```